# Having installed PHP7 can i also use php5_module along?

Tags: php, php-7.2

I just upgraded from php5.6. => php7.2.5
All of my websites are working except one that it only workd correctly with the php5_module and not with the php7_module.

Is there soem way to only have installed php7.2.5 but also use the php5_module as well?

This the error iam getting from a domain when i upgraded from php56 => php72

> [Mon May 21 10:33:21.490109 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19775] [client 66.249.66.193:39398] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function split() in /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/library/misc.php:19\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/library/navigation.php(271): theme_trim_long_str('\xCE\x91\xCF\x81\xCF\x87\xCE\xB9\xCE\xBA\xCE\xAE', '45')\n#1 /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/library/navigation.php(343): theme_MenuItem->get_start(0)\n#2 /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/library/navigation.php(315): theme_MenuWalker->display('', Array)\n#3 /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/library/navigation.php(92): theme_MenuWalker->walk(Array, Array)\n#4 /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/library/navigation.php(17): theme_get_list_menu(Array)\n#5 /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/header.php(62): theme_get_menu(Array)\n#6 /home/akis/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(688...\n'

Comment: 1. you should try to fix that application instead of looking for a workaround.

Comment: Does it use the mysql_ extension?

Comment: 2. you can _not_ operate two php modules inside a single http server process. You _can_ have different versions installed, but you need to trigger them using different strategies. One as a module maybe, the other using a fastcgi container or similar.

Comment: 3. reading the error message which claims that the function `split()` is not defined" I would guess that you did not install the `posix` php extension.

Comment: The theme developer should have updated the theme to be compatible with PHP7 by now, as it looks like the errors are stemming from that.  Is there an update available?

Comment: I have created the webpage myself neither iam a php programmer. should i just install "yum install php-posix" ? Would that fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your error states:

> Call to undefined function split()

After a quick google search I found this article in the PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

> Warning. This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Alternatives to this function include:

- [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)
- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Please conciser using one of the alternatives.

This is why you shouldn't use deprecated functions when writing code, because they will soon disappear and your code will crash when upgrading versions.

Comment: Hello, i have written the code myself neither the web designer did. Could you please direct me on to what should i chnage on the file /home/akis/public_html/wp-content/themes/business_for_sale_1-1/library/navigation.php so that domain varsa.gr will be displayed propetly? iam not a php programmer. if you want i can post the relative code from the file navigation.php

Comment: It was easy after all. I changed the line inside misc.php from $words = split($sep, $str); ===> $words = preg_split($sep, $str); and now http://varsa.gr works perfectly!!! 1000 thanks Joas!

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος Glad I could help and happy to see you could figure out the converting yourself.

Comment: I couldn't have done if it wasn't your direction!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. why not, you can have both versions installed. And you can **enable** or **disable** your PHP versions using the below commands if your are on a linux machine (ubuntu)

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2 (**Replace it with your PHP7 version**)
sudo a2enmod php5.6 (**To enable your PHP5.x version**)
sudo service apache2 restart (**Restart Apache**)
```

Again, if you want to enable 7.2 just replace it vice versa.

**Note :** Remember though, you can't have both versions working at the same time.

Comment: That hardly is a solution, since you still can only operate one version _at a time_, with is typically required for a web server if it is to host multiple applications.

Comment: Agreed. we can't use same versions simultaneously

Comment: Your now added "note" is not entirely correct, you _can_ operate different php versions simultaneously. You are just limited to a single version to be used as a module in the http server. There are other options though: cgi, fastcgi, fpm, ... Also you can use a second backend server and proxy requests through to that one which operates the different php version. Many options...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give https://github.com/cfebs/phpvm a go, this works well with my local environment.

Another option is to use Docker, create a container with both PHP versions and put your app into those containers to compare. Another good thing with a docker is that you can change docker-compose file to a version that suits you best.